# R: Merge each dataframe in a list with a different column in a dataframe

Tags: r, lapply, mapply

I am trying to merge each dataframe in a list of dataframes with a different column of a single dataframe. That is, the dataframe in list element 1 should be merged with row 1 of the single dataframe, the dataframe in list element 2 should be merged with row 2 of the single dataframe and so on. It's easier to understand with an example.

Here is my list of dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 11:14, col2 = 11:14)
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = 12:15, col2 = 12:15)
df3 <- data.frame(col1 = 13:16, col2 = 13:16)

df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

So `df_list` looks like this:

```
[[1]]
  col1 col2
1   11   11
2   12   12
3   13   13
4   14   14

[[2]]
  col1 col2
1   12   12
2   13   13
3   14   14
4   15   15

[[3]]
  col1 col2
1   13   13
2   14   14
3   15   15
4   16   16
```

Here is my single dataframe:

```
df_to_merge <- data.frame(col3 = 1:3, col4 = 4:6)
```

```
  col3 col4
1    1    4
2    2    5
3    3    6
```

I can easily achieve the result I want with a loop:

```
what_i_want <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(df_to_merge)) {
  what_i_want[[i]] <- merge.data.frame(df_list[[i]], df_to_merge[i, ])
}
```

Which gives:

```
[[1]]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   11   11    1    4
2   12   12    1    4
3   13   13    1    4
4   14   14    1    4

[[2]]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   12   12    2    5
2   13   13    2    5
3   14   14    2    5
4   15   15    2    5

[[3]]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   13   13    3    6
2   14   14    3    6
3   15   15    3    6
4   16   16    3    6
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this with a combination of e.g. `lapply()` and `apply()`? Or `mapply()`? I tried, but the only thing I could manage was to combine each element of the list with **each** row of the single dataframe, which I don't want.

Thanks in advance for any creative solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically there now:

```
what_i_want <- lapply(seq_along(df_list), function(i) { merge.data.frame(df_list[[i]], df_to_merge[i,]) })
```

Result:

```
> what_i_want
[[1]]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   11   11    1    4
2   12   12    1    4
3   13   13    1    4
4   14   14    1    4

[[2]]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   12   12    2    5
2   13   13    2    5
3   14   14    2    5
4   15   15    2    5

[[3]]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   13   13    3    6
2   14   14    3    6
3   15   15    3    6
4   16   16    3    6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` `df_to_merge` at each row and use `Map` to `cbind`

```
Map(cbind, df_list, split(df_to_merge, seq_len(nrow(df_to_merge))))

#[1]]
#  col1 col2 col3 col4
#1   11   11    1    4
#2   12   12    1    4
#3   13   13    1    4
#4   14   14    1    4

#[[2]]
#  col1 col2 col3 col4
#1   12   12    2    5
#2   13   13    2    5
#3   14   14    2    5
#4   15   15    2    5

#[[3]]
#  col1 col2 col3 col4
#1   13   13    3    6
#2   14   14    3    6
#3   15   15    3    6
#4   16   16    3    6
```

---

A `tidyverse` way of the same logic could be

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map2(df_list, df_to_merge %>% group_split(row_number(), keep = FALSE), cbind)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `lapply()` and `cbind()`

```
dfout <- lapply(seq(df_list), function(k) cbind(df_list[[k]],df_to_merge[k,],row.names = NULL))
```

such that

```
> dfout
[[1]]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   11   11    1    4
2   12   12    1    4
3   13   13    1    4
4   14   14    1    4

[[2]]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   12   12    2    5
2   13   13    2    5
3   14   14    2    5
4   15   15    2    5

[[3]]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   13   13    3    6
2   14   14    3    6
3   15   15    3    6
4   16   16    3    6
```